# I want Upgrade Umbraco 4.11.6 to 4.11.9

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, upgrade

When I Upgrading Umbraco 4.11.6 to 4.11.9, I encounter a problem.
I copied /bin, /install, /Umbraco, /Umbraco_Client folders from Umbraco4.11.9 to umbraco4.11.6 for upgrade([enter link description here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/Upgrading/general))
after, I rebuild project and run it.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. ]
   System.Convert.FromBase64_ComputeResultLength(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength) +10545429
   System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength) +71
   System.Convert.FromBase64CharArray(Char[] inArray, Int32 offset, Int32 length) +90
   System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.UrlTokenDecode(String input) +168
   System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(String encryptedTicket) +9571032
   Umbraco.Core.StringExtensions.DecryptWithMachineKey(String value) in d:\Google Drive\Dev\UmbracoSource_v4\src\Umbraco.Core\StringExtensions.cs:75
   umbraco.BasePages.BasePage.get_umbracoUserContextID() +141
   umbraco.logout.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   umbraco.BasePages.BasePage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +59
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

**How can I solve it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try clearing your cookies, I mostly only see errors like this when I am logged in before doing the upgrade. If you clear cookies to log yourself out it should clear the error.